LinkTo fails on click
I generate a link as:
<td><LinkTo @route="assets.asset" @model="{{asset.id}}">{{asset.id}}</LinkTo></td>

The link is generated correctly. When I click nothing happens. The inspector shows an error like:
Error while computing: arguments
Error while computing: caller

My routes are:
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('assets', function(){
    this.route('asset', { path: '/:id' });
  });
});


assets route hanldler:
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default class AssetsRoute extends Route {
  @service store;
  async model() {
    return this.store.findAll('asset');
  }
}


asset handler looks like:
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default class AssetRoute extends Route {
  @service store;
  async model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('asset', params.id);
  }
}


Any suggestion?

I don't think you should have quotes around the @model variable. This happens to me quite a bit because Visual Studio Code "helpfully" adds them as I'm typing. Try this instead:
<td><LinkTo @route="assets.asset" @model={{asset.id}}>{{asset.id}}</LinkTo></td>


Thanks. I have tried it but I get the same error. Is there a way to debug this error? I am not sure if this may have a role but I am using the RestSerializer.

@AndreaCampolonghi How about putting {{log asset}} into the template? Could you also update your question with the route.js and some more of the template for context so we know where asset is coming from.

I have added my routes handlers in the questions. The log asset is pretty big. What is the interesting part for you to help me debug? It looks like the store uses a JSONApiCache adapter. Could that conflict with me using a RestSerializer?

Solved. Looks like I was starting the local server with ember serve and not with npm start.

Glad you're sorted. I'm confused tho as Npm start normally resolves to ember serve anyway. I was going to recommend seeing what is in asset.id seeing as that is what you are passing

I agree with you.
